# Prepublish not working as expected

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab, npm-install

I am testing on npm scripts to build my project dependency.

My idea comes from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server which impressed me by code in repository doesn't mean code in node_modules after `npm install`.

Below is my testmodule structure

```
src/index.js
package.json
```

and this is my package.json content

```
{
  "name": "testmodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src/ -d lib/",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2"
  }
}
```

and this is structure I expect after run `npm install testmodule`

```
node_modules/testmodule/lib/index.js
node_modules/testmodule/package.json
```

which is src folder should not be here.

But after I run `npm install`, it is exactly the same as when I push to my git repository.

Please take note that I am using [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) in my own server.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anything that i'm missing to make prepublish run?
2. Which part of parse-server code makes the src folder and other files not there after install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running `npm install`?

According to the [documentation on npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), the prepublish script is run "BEFORE the package is published. (Also run on local npm install without any arguments.)". It seems clear that the prepublish script is only run on `npm publish` or `npm install <local directory>`.

If you are trying to install directly from your local gitlab server via a URL, this will **not** work - the script will not be run. The solution would be to install locally unless you're willing to open source your package & push it to the npm repository or pay for a private npm repository. This is what I have done during development of packages before they're ready to be made public.

Comment: Got it for prepublish. Thank you. But mind explain how parse-server remove src, resources folder and other file during publish?

Comment: FWIW, I know nothing about parse-server, but it looks like the package is installed from the npm repository. Therefore, at some point the developer did an `npm publish` and pushed the code to the npm repository. And that's when the parse-server prepublish script is run.

Answer (score 1):

<del>`prepublish`</del> is deprecated. Use `prepublishOnly` or `prepare`.

> **prepublish** (DEPRECATED)
>
> - Does not run during `npm publish`, but does run during `npm ci` and `npm install`...
>
> **prepublishOnly**
>
> - Runs BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on `npm publish`.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts

Comment: That was the solution for me!